# Guidelines to follow when making your program Active Directory/Terminal Services compatible

Tags: active-directory, directoryservices, terminal-services

Wondering if there's any guidelines that should be followed when writing an application that should work not only on a plain ol' non-networked computer but also on a computer/network that is setup with Active Directory (or some other directory service) and/or Terminal Services? Anything I should look out for, be aware of, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft has renamed Terminal Services to 'Remote Desktop Services' so searching and looking around MSDN my not be as constructive using the old terminology.
I'd start having a look around Remote *Desktop Services Programming Guidelines* found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383490(VS.85).aspx

Comment: Looks like some good stuff, thanks for pointing those resources out.

Answer (score 1):

On the AD site a starting point would be here:

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682458(VS.85).aspx][2]

Answer (score 1):

The most important things to be aware of:
On a Terminal Server users are not admins, they have no rights to:

- Write in Program files folder
- Register ActiveX controls
- Write into (ini files) in Windows(\System32)
- HKLM hive of the registry

Some other points:
 - Certain API's like getting the Windows directory will return redirected results (in this case the windows subfolder of the homedrive) UNLESS you mark your executable as [Terminal Server aware](http://www.remkoweijnen.nl/blog/2007/11/24/delphi-and-terminal-server-aware/)
 - Your application must not rely on settings in HKCU that prevent startup when not present
 - Multiple users might use your app concurrently so each user must be able to have their own settings (in HKCU)